# MySQL Query: Simplifying Subqueries and Union

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following columns: match_id, player_slot, ability, level

There are 10 player slots per match and each hero can have up to 25 levels and one of five abilities. I'm pulling the data from an API and need the pulls to be fast so I don't have much flexibility with how my table is set up.

However for displaying the data, I'm really struggling to turn the existing table format into something that is workable. For each match, I'd like to have the data laid out like this:

player slot1, ability at level 1, ability at level 2, ..., ability at level 16

...

player slot10, ability at level 1, ability at level 2, ..., ability at level 16

I can get a working example ( [Here's an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zDHO.png) ) up but it's a really ugly query. For each row I have 15 nested subqueries and then perform a UNION to join each of the 10 rows.

Snippet of the query:

```
SELECT player_slot, ability,
(SELECT ability FROM api_abilities WHERE match_id = 119009486 AND player_slot = 1 AND level = 2 ),
...
(SELECT ability FROM api_abilities WHERE match_id = 119009486 AND player_slot = 1 AND level = 16 )
FROM api_abilities
WHERE match_id = 119009486 AND player_slot = 1 AND level = 1
```

How would I go about simplifying this? Should I make a view or a new table with this data presented in a different way? Also complicating this is that each player will end the game at different levels. What I have now does work but it seems that there has to be a more efficient way to run the query. I've tried a few different things but can't seem to get the row consolidations correct on my other queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
SELECT a.player_slot
     , MAX(IF(a.level=1,a.ability,NULL)) AS ability_at_level_1
     , MAX(IF(a.level=2,a.ability,NULL)) AS ability_at_level_2
     , MAX(IF(a.level=3,a.ability,NULL)) AS ability_at_level_3
     , MAX(IF(a.level=4,a.ability,NULL)) AS ability_at_level_4
     , MAX(IF(a.level=5,a.ability,NULL)) AS ability_at_level_5
   ...   
     , MAX(IF(a.level=15,a.ability,NULL)) AS ability_at_level_15
     , MAX(IF(a.level=16,a.ability,NULL)) AS ability_at_level_16
  FROM api_abilities a
WHERE a.match_id = 119009486
  AND a.player_slot >= 1
  AND a.player_slot <= 10
GROUP
   BY a.player_slot
```

If you wanted the query to return more than one `match_id`, you would want the `GROUP BY` clause to include the `match_id` column before `player_slot`, (as well as including it in the SELECT list.

```
GROUP
   BY a.match_id
    , a.player_slot
```

For best performance, you'll want a suitable index.  A covering index would (likely) give the best query performance:

```
ON api_abilities (match_id, player_slot, level, ability)
```

The reason this is a suitable index is because you have an equality predicate on the `match_id` column, and a range predicate and a GROUP BY on the `player_slot` column. (This index is still suitable even if the range predicate on player_slot is removed.) The inclusion of the `level` and `ability` columns aren't strictly necessary, but including them makes the index a "covering index". It's called a "covering index" because the query can be satisfied entirely from the index (the EXPLAIN output will show "Using index") without needing to visit the data page underlying the index.

The use of the MAX aggregate and the IF function is what allows us to "pick out" the a.ability from the appropriate row. (The "trick" is that for any row that isn't at the specified level, the IF function is returning a NULL. What we are really doing with the MAX is throwing out those NULL values.

If `(match_id, player_slot, level)` is unique, then that MAX aggregate function will be operating on one `a.ability` value and a bunch of NULLs. In the more general case, if we don't have that guaranteed to be unique, then there's the possibility that the MAX aggregate would be operating on two (or more) non-NULL `a.ability` values. In that more general case, a GROUP_CONCAT aggregate function might be useful (in place of the MAX) if you wanted to return a short list of `a.ability` (as a string) at each level.

Comment: @Nitin Midha: yes, the predicates on player_slot (>=1 and <= 10) could be removed from the query; but it's not clear from the OP whether that  limit of 10 player slots is to be enforced by the query, or whether that's a limitation in the underlying data.

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick. The limitation of 10 player slots is a limitation in the underlying data so it works fine without the a.player_slot items in the WHERE clause

Comment: @user1723535: good to hear this is working for you. I did notice that the answer from bluefeet also includes a query that uses the same approach.

Answer (score 1):

This type of transformation is a *pivot*.  Unfortunately, MySQL does not have a pivot function so you will need to replicate it using multiple joins or aggregate functions.

You can use multiple joins instead of the subqueries:

```
SELECT 
  l1.player_slot, 
  l1.ability Level1Ability,
  l2.ability Level2Ability,
  l16.ability Level16Ability
FROM api_abilities l1
LEFT JOIN api_abilities l2
  on l1.match_id = l2.match_id 
  and l1.player_slot = l2.player_slot
  and l2.level = 2
-- .... add more joins for each level
LEFT JOIN api_abilities l16
  on l1.match_id = l16.match_id 
  and l1.player_slot = l16.player_slot
  and l16.level = 16
WHERE l1.match_id = 119009486 
  AND l1.player_slot >= 1
  AND l1.player_slot <= 10
  AND l1.level = 1
```

Or you can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression:

```
select
  player_slot,
  max(case when level = 1 then ability end) Level1Ability,
  max(case when level = 2 then ability end) Level2Ability,
  -- ... add more case expressions for each level
FROM api_abilities 
where match_id = 119009486 
  and player_slot >= 1
  and player_slot <= 10
group by player_shot
```

Comment: @NitinMidha why? In the original query they are using the `match_id` and `player_slot`.  It might be incorrect to remove that join condition. The OP would have to further clarify what they are trying to do.

Comment: As per his question "For each row I have 15 nested subqueries and then perform a UNION to join each of the 10 rows." The snippet he showed is repeated for player_slot from 1 to 10, so i assumed that your answer cater to all his needs ...

Comment: Thanks, this answer also worked. Sorry I can't give you both credit for an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you need to get a better understanding of database normalization. I'm still not exactly sure what you are trying to do here based on your description, but it seems clear to me that this data should be represented across multiple tables (one for matches, one for players, one for abilities, one relating players to abilities and ability levels, one relating players to matches, etc.).

Comment: I do have other tables for matches, players, etc. It seems a bit excessive to me to break down the api_ability table into multiple parts as the points by themselves don't convey much information. An ability without a level doesn't tell me anything and without the match_id and player_slot the rows would not be unique. I guess I could split this table into a bunch of sub-tables and relate them with a constructed key (a separate table that just has the constructed key and the level, etc) but is that really preferred? Plus the multiple inserts might hurt my API script run time.